# nodeJS: running a batch of childprocess commands in a waterfall

Tags: node.js, git, child-process

I am trying to *elegantly* run five git commands one after the other while maintaining the ability to catch error and progress:

- git status
- git pull
- git add .
- git commit -am "commit message"
- git push

*Open source note: I've studied different node-git libraries and decided for different reasons to implement it on my own.*

Using [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), I've created a deferred method to run child processes:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec,
    path = require('path'),
    Q = require('q'),
    gitPath = path.resolve(__dirname + "/../projects/langs");


function run(command) {

    var deferred = Q.defer();

    exec(command, {cwd: gitPath}, function puts(error, stdout, stderr) {

        if (error) {
            deferred.reject(new Error(error));
        } else {
            deferred.resolve(stdout);
        }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

However, I want to avoid the [Pyramid of doom](http://tritarget.org/blog/2012/11/28/the-pyramid-of-doom-a-javascript-style-trap/):

```
function option1() {
    // Pyramid of doom

    run("git status").then(function (output) {
        console.log(output);

        run("git pull").then(function (output) {
            console.log(output);

            run("git add .").then(function (output) {
                console.log(output);   
                // etc.    
            });

        });
    });
}
```

And doesn't feel quite elegant:

```
function options1a() {
    // Pyramid of doom

    run("git status").then(function (output) {
        console.log(output);

        run("git pull");
    }).then(function (output) {
            console.log(output);
            run("git add .")
        }).then(function (output) {
            console.log(output);

        });
}
```

I saw a third option but can't seem to get it to work:

```
function promiseWaterfall(tasks) {
    var resolvedPromise = Q(undefined);

    var finalTaskPromise = tasks.reduce(function (prevTaskPromise, task) {
        return prevTaskPromise.then(task);
    }, resolvedPromise);  // initial value

    return finalTaskPromise;
}

promiseWaterfall([
    run("git status"),
    run("git pull"),
    run("git add .")
]).then(function () {
        console.log(arguments);
    });
```

And I'm playing with a fourth option of using the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
        callback(null, 'one', 'two');
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, callback){
        callback(null, 'three');
    },
    function(arg1, callback){
        // arg1 now equals 'three'
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
], function (err, result) {
    // result now equals 'done'    
});
```

But this seems to take me towards a non-promises path.

How do I get it to work elegantly? any best practices?

Answer (score 2):

I'm familiar with [when.js promises](https://github.com/cujojs/when) so I will answer your question with that promise library. It provides helper functions for this sort of thing similar to the callback based async lib. Check out their [API documentation](https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/master/docs/api.md) for more examples.

In the following code I am using the `when/sequence` module to perform what you are looking for. I've also modified your code organization a little to keep things somewhat modular (e.g. not embedding the git cwd inside of the `run` function in your example).

Here is a fully working implementation. Make sure to change out the git cwd to your own git repository as it's currently pointing to one of my own.

```js
var exec = require('child_process').exec
, when = require('when')
, sequence = require('when/sequence');

// simple promise wrapper for exec
function exec_p(command, options) {
    options = options || {};
    var defer = when.defer();
    exec(command, options, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        return error 
            ? defer.reject(stderr + new Error(error.stack || error))
            : defer.resolve(stdout);
    });
    return defer.promise;
}

// Some simple git wrapper
function Git(config) {
    var self = this;
    self.config = config;
    return function(gitCommand) {
        return exec_p('git ' + gitCommand, self.config);
    };
}

// create a new instnace of git and specify our options
var git = new Git({ cwd: "/home/trev/git/tsenior" });

// we can now use sequence & our newly created git wrapper to easily
// can things in order one after another
sequence([
    function() { return git('status'); },
    function() { return git('status'); },
    function() { return git('status'); },
    function() { return git('status'); }
]).then(function(results) { // handle the results here
    console.log(results);
}).otherwise(function(error) { // handle any errors here
    console.error(error.stack || error);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

The code provided doesn't `console.log` after every step (it just logs out the results at the end), but it can be easily modified to do so.